# Jquery Wrapping

Tags: jquery

This is my input  i have like 120 lines of code like this one and the city names are not limited, there are 20 cities at this moment but it might go up like 40 or even 60.

```
<a href="somelink" rel="city3">Name1</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city2">Name2</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name4</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city4">Name6</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city3">Name5</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name3</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city4">Name7</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name8</a><br>
```

and i need this output to group them and give a title named the city they belong

```
<h1>city1</h1>
<div class="gather">
<a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name4</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name3</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name8</a><br>
</div>
<h1>city2</h1>
<div class="gather">
<a href="somelink" rel="city2">Name2</a><br>
</div>
<h1>city3</h1>
<div class="gather">
<a href="somelink" rel="city3">Name1</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city3">Name5</a><br>
</div>
<h1>city4</h1>
<div class="gather">
<a href="somelink" rel="city4">Name6</a><br>
<a href="somelink" rel="city4">Name7</a><br>
</div>
```

i believe wrapper is the thing im looking for

Comment: So, where's your jquery code?

Comment: And how are we supposed to know how you want these grouped?

Comment: i need the code isnt that obvious. I need that output and dont know HOW

Comment: they are gonna seperated by rel as you see

Comment: I see, well, then try something and come back with some code and we will help you then...

Comment: besides showing the basic code, how is the <a> element list generated? because if it is some sort of server side it would be easier to handle the transformation there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select each of the sets of elements by their `rel` attribute, then append them into another structure. If you `.append()` an element somewhere that already exists in the DOM, it will be moved:

```
$(function () {

    //get all the links that have a `rel` attribute that starts with `city`
    var $links = $('#container').children('a[rel^="city"]'),

        //setup an output variable to sort the links
        output = {};

    //iterate through each of the links and add them to an object sorted by `rel` attribute
    $.each($links, function (index, element) {

        //get the number after `city` in the `rel` attribute
        var cityNumber = $(element).attr('rel').substr(4);

        //if this index does not exist, make it
        if (typeof output[cityNumber] == 'undefined') {
            output[cityNumber] = [];
        }

        //push element into proper index
        output[cityNumber].push(element);
    });

    //remove the container's HTML
    $('#container').empty();

    //loop through the `output` object
    $.each(output, function (index, obj) {

        //append a new set of links for each index (sorted by `rel` attribute)
        $('#container').append('<h1>city' + index + '</h1>').append($('<div />', { class : 'gather' }).append(obj));
    });
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d2FKS/1/

Comment: $(function () {
    var $links = $('#container').children('a[rel]'),
        output = {};
    $.each($links, function (index, element) {
        var cityNumber = $(element).attr('rel');
        if (typeof output[cityNumber] == 'undefined') {
            output[cityNumber] = [];
        }
        output[cityNumber].push(element);
    });
    $('#container').empty();
    $.each(output, function (index, obj) {
        $('#container').append('<h1>' + index + '</h1>').append($('<div />', { class : 'gather' }).append(obj));
    });
});

edited it this way now this one also works for me 

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that can get you started:

```
$('a').each(function(i, el) {
    var e = $(el);
    if(e.parent().attr('class') != 'gather') {
        var rel = e.attr('rel');
        var a = $('a[rel=' + rel + ']');
        var aAndBr = a.add(a.next());
        var div = aAndBr.wrapAll('<div class="gather">').parent();
        var h1 = $('<h1>').text(rel).insertBefore(div);
    }
});
```

jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/647s8/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want `wrapAll`, but that's not your only problem. You also need to only run the wrap once for each city, but you don't know how many cities you have. Furthermore, the cities don't seem to occur in any predictable order, so we'll have to assume order doesn't matter. Then you have to capture the city names and apply them in `h2`s.

```
var seenRels = {};
$('a[rel^="city"]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), thisRel = $this.attr('rel');
    if (!(thisRel in seenRels)) {
        var $group = $this.siblings('a[rel="' + thisRel + '"]').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="gather">');
        seenRels[thisRel] = 1;
    }
});
$('div.gather').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this), thisCity = $this.children('a').attr('rel');
    $this.before('<h2>' + thisCity + '</h2>');
});
```

Finally, you'll want to clean up those `br`s, which I leave as an exercise because my kid is crying.

http://jsfiddle.net/MB858/1/

Comment: changed $('a[rel]')
and now its working perfectly

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After putting your cities in a parent div like this:

```
<div id="cities">
    <a href="somelink" rel="city3">Name1</a><br>
    <a href="somelink" rel="city2">Name2</a><br>
    <a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name4</a><br>
    <a href="somelink" rel="city4">Name6</a><br>
    <a href="somelink" rel="city3">Name5</a><br>
    <a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name3</a><br>
    <a href="somelink" rel="city4">Name7</a><br>
    <a href="somelink" rel="city1">Name8</a><br>
</div>​
```

This code will group them by rel value with the desired header and structure oputput them sorted by rel value:

```
$("#go").click(function() {
    var index = {};
    var keys = [];
    var cities = $("#cities"), gather, key, len;
    // go through each city and put it into the index
    // build a list of keys along the way so we can sort them
    $("a", cities).each(function() {
        var rel = this.rel;
        if (!(rel in index)) {
            keys.push(rel);
            index[rel] = [];
        }
        index[rel].push(this);
    });
    // clear cities div
    cities.html("");
    // now index has an array for each city name
    // sort the keys by only the digits at the end
    keys.sort(function(a,b) {
        return(parseInt(a.replace("city", ""), 10) - parseInt(b.replace("city", ""), 10));
    });
    // for each city in the index
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        key = keys[i];
        // create title
        cities.append("<h1>" + key + "</h1>");
        // create gather div
        gather = $('<div class="gather"></div>');
        // iterate through the instances of this city and 
        // add them to the gather object
        for (var j = 0, len = index[key].length; j < len; j++) {
            gather.append(index[key][j]);
            gather.append("<br>");
        }
        cities.append(gather);
    }
});​
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jG5gP/

Answer (score 0):

This was my go at it.

```
$(function(){
  var cities = $('a[rel^="city"]');   
  $.each(cities, function(i,value){
    cityNum = $(value).attr('rel').split('city');
    cityNum = cityNum[1];   
    $('a[rel="city'+i+'"]').wrapAll('<div class="gather" />').filter('a:first').before('<h3> City: '+cityNum+' </h3>'); 
  });   
});
```